# Connection to table error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to list the contents of a remote SQL Server db. The error is occurring in the Controller.
I am getting a NullReference Error after doing some debugging I noticed that the table isn't being found. So I'm not sure if its the connection string or if I'm missing something. The table shows up fine in the server explorer but it doesn't show up under App Data. Any ideas?

Model:

**RegionalSalesManagers.cs**

```
public class RegionalSalesManagers
{
    [Key]
    public string   Code { get; set; }
    public char Name { get; set; }
}
```

**RegionalSalesManConnection.cs**

```
public class RegionalSalesManConnection : DbContext
{
    public RegionalSalesManConnection() : base("RegionalSalesManConnection") { }

    public DbSet<RegionalSalesManagers > RegionalManagers { get; set; }    
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
<add name="RegionalSalesManConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=01DEV\SQLDEV01;Database=Caplugs_Nav_Data;Trusted_Connection=Yes" />
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    RegionalSalesManConnection db = new RegionalSalesManConnection();

    public ViewResult Index() {

        var model = db.RegionalManagers.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@foreach(item in Model){
@Html.DisplayFor(item.Code, item.Name)
}
```

Comment: show your View. how did you set the ViewModel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HomeController` is not actually passing the model to the view, so without further information on where the exception is being raised (or stacktrace details), it could be the cause.

So some suggested changes:

- Use a constructor to create the database context
- Pass `model` to the view via  `View(model)`

Which would look like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    private RegionalSalesManConnection _db;

    public HomeController() {
        _db = new RegionalSalesManConnection();
    }

    public ViewResult Index() {
       var model = db.RegionalManagers.ToList();
       return View(model);
    }
}
```